# NextJS Dynamic List Not Updating on Delete/Update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

Currently, my react/nextjs dynamic list is not updating correctly, I've given an array to map so it'll show a new row on frame update since it's stored on useState, Usually, the issue is with the key of the list that is not unique, but my key is unique

Heres my code

```
const [allSelectedMaterials, setAllSelectedMaterials] = useState([]) // This variable stores a javascript object into the array
{console.log('-- Updated --')}
{allSelectedMaterials.map((material, i) => {
    const key = Object.keys(material).toString()
    console.log(`${i} - [${key}] ${material}`)

    return (
        <div key={key}>
            <Row className='align-items-center'>
                <Col xs='auto'>
                    <h6>{material[key].name}</h6>
                </Col>
                <Col>
                    <Button variant='danger' className='mb-1' onClick={() => handleDeleteMaterial(key)}>
                        Remove
                    </Button>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <InputGroup>
                <InputGroup.Text>
                    <Image src={material[key].image} className={`${styles.allMaterialsImage}`} />
                </InputGroup.Text>
                <Form.Control type='number' min={1} ref={(e) => (selectedMaterials.current[i] = e)} required />
            </InputGroup>
            <div className='mt-1' />
        </div>
    )
})}
```

The problem is after I added the first item on the list and adding a new one it won't update the view, here's the console output

[image]

And here's me adding a second entry to the list

[image]

It clearly says on the log that the array (stored in useState) is updated but it's not changing the view it's still the same as the previous one. But if I reupdate the frame by updating any useState variable it updated the list

**Update:
Here's my code for adding new material**
(loadedMaterials is just a list of materials that is retrieved from an API)

```
const handleAddSelectedMaterial = () => {
    loadedMaterials.map((material) => {
        const key = Object.keys(material)
        if (key == currentSelectedMaterial) {
            let _material
            if (allSelectedMaterials.length > 0) _material = allSelectedMaterials
            else _material = []

            _material.push({ [material[key].id]: material[key] })
            setAllSelectedMaterials(_material)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Add only the necessary information to help others go through your code and help you. Now there's a lot of information and its difficult for others to go over them all.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I've rewrote the question so it's easier to understand with the issue

Comment: Can you add this line -> 
useEffect(() => {} , [allSelectedMaterials])
And see if it works for you

Comment: @Zurez tried it and still doesn't work also what's interesting is that it didn't call the useEffect at all even though it should call it due to the value on the dependency changed (allSelectedMaterial). But the view still changes correctly after if I update/re-render from updating any other useState

Comment: The code block which you have shared, is it actual or just pseudocode? If it is a real code , then I see problem here.

Comment: It's a real code that is being used in the app, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: @juliomalves added in the question at the bottom

Comment: Rather than calling `setAllSelectedMaterials` in every iteration of `loadedMaterials.map` I'd suggest you return the array from that `map` and _then_ set `setAllSelectedMaterials(returnedArrayFromMap)`.

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing
from

```
 _material.push({ [material[key].id]: material[key] })
            setAllSelectedMaterials(_material)
```

to

```
 _material.push({ [material[key].id]: material[key] })
            setAllSelectedMaterials([..._material])
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the input and responses, but I've managed to solve this issue by redoing how the form & dynamic list work and it's working perfectly now.

If anyone is wondering I just basically follow this person implementation on a dynamic list
https://www.cluemediator.com/add-or-remove-input-fields-dynamically-with-reactjs